# How to add pointers to an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, pointers

```
test = 'Don\'t display this'
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4]

ar[0] = test
test = 'I want to retrieve this'

print ar[0] # 'Don't display this'
```

How do I add a pointer to an array? Everything is passed by reference I read but apparently not in these cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write your code as below, to meet your need.

```
test = 'Don\'t display this'
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4]

ar[0] = test
test.replace 'I want to retrieve this'

print ar[0]
```

`test` is a local variable, which can hold *any type* of object. In your first *assignment* it held one object, and in the second assignment, it is holding another brand new *string* object. If you want to work with the *same string object*, [`String#replace`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-replace) is one option to go.

Comment: In Ruby, (almost) every variable is in fact a reference/pointer to an object. So in fact, you are using pointers all the time.

If you want to do pointer arithmetic as in C, this is not possible with Ruby.

Comment: Then it is sadly not possible. The test variable is changed and edited by various methods all over the place (including those not written by me). I guess I just have to write/alias a setter and set the array value there every time... I was hoping for a C-pointer-solution.

Comment: @Napoleon: You should have put that in your question. We are not aware of your requirements.

Comment: Arup did provice a working solution. But it's still not a 'real pointer solution'. But it's as far as Ruby goes I guess.

Comment: @staticx Your first comment is too much perfect.

Comment: @Napoleon Did you read the first comment what staticx made ? If you read it, why still expecting it from Ruby. Yes, you need to take different strategy.